# preg_match rejects the character '|'

Tags: php, html, string

how to use preg match to see if special characters "|" exist in a string?
My current code is bellow

```
            $string = "|preg_matchtest";
            if (preg_match("/|/",$string))
            { 
                 echo "Succsess!!";
            }
           else
            {
             echo "failer";
            }
```

it will print failer message in output.

Comment: How about escaping special characters (like alternative character `|`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backslash

```
preg_match("/\|/", $string)
```

Also you coud use [preg_quote](http://php.net/preg_quote)(there is list of special characters) function

```
$search_string = preg_quote('|');
preg_match("/".$search_string."/", $string)
```